# Issue on SVG group translation with d3.js

Tags: svg, translation

I am trying to drag a svg group (I am using D3.js)
According to the code, I thought that should be working, but the element movement seems to be "dragging" (move slower than the mouse mouvement). Actually, the shape is make kind of 2 points forward for 1 point backward. 
Here is the code

"this.parentNode" is a svg group already translated. I use this translation coord as a starting point for the new translation

function dragged() {

```
let initX = d3.transform(this.parentNode.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0]
let initY = d3.transform(this.parentNode.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]

console.log(initX)

console.log(d3.event.dx)

console.log(initX + d3.event.dx)

d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform", "translate(" + (initX + d3.event.dx) + "," + (initY + d3.event.dy) + ")");
```

}

Comment: I think we're going to need a complete [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I finally used d3.event.x instead of d3.event.dx

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform", "translate(" + (initX + d3.event.x) + "," + (initY + d3.event.y) + ")");
```

I don't really understand why is this `x` more accurate than this `dx` but now it works flawlessly.

Edit :
Using `d3.event.x` is not good, because in a `<g>` tag, children elements are positioned using x and y coordinates. This creates some issues while dragging. 
I am finally using `d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX`